# Unable to get specific record from PHP two multi dimensional array by loop

Tags: php, arrays

It might be difficult to understand .. please ask if u have any doubt.
there are two array

```
$firstArray=array(array('startDate'=>'5-05-2016',endDate=>'10-05-2016')
array('startDate'=>'5-06-2016',endDate=>'10-0-2016')); //multiple   records
$secondArray=array(array('date'=>'07-05-2016',array('date'=>'07-06-2016')));  //multiple recods

// this is what I tried
if($firstArray){
foreach($firstArrat $intArr){


  if($secondArray){
        foreach($secondArray as $sArr){
            if (($intArr['startDate'] < $sArr['date']) && ($intArr['endDate'] > $sArr['date'])){
                 echo $sArr['date'];
            }
             else{
                echo $sArr['date'];
            }
           }
          }
        }
```

I need to get the specific data from second array if date is between and first array start date and end date.looping second array in first array loop not helping me out.records duplicating.only one record should be match. Please help . stuck in middle of ocean.

Comment: Did you try anything?

Comment: Yes. I tried to get by looping scond array loop in first array but it didnt help.records duplicating. if record match that record has to go to the another array . if doesnt match it has to go to another array.

Comment: To clarify, you have,
`$firstArray = array(array('startDate'=>'5-05-2016',endDate=>'10-05-2016'), ...))`?

Comment: array_push($firstArray , array('startDate' => $startDate, 'endDate' => $endDate, 'principalRepayment' => $totalamount));

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just do this, using a loop to secondArray you can check is it between the first array start and end or not. `$firstArray` must have these two entries.

Check this online [Online test](https://3v4l.org/7ZKnM).

> Convert each time to time stamp using `strtotime`.

```
$firstArray = array(
                array('startDate' => '05-05-2016', 'endDate' => '10-05-2016'), 
                array('startDate' => '05-06-2016', 'endDate' => '10-07-2016'), 
                array('startDate' => '05-08-2016', 'endDate' => '10-11-2016')
            );

$secondArray = array(array('date' => '07-05-2016'), array('date' => '12-07-2016'), array('date' => '12-11-2016'));

function find_match($index){
    global $firstArray, $secondArray;
    foreach($secondArray as $date){
        if(strtotime($date['date']) > strtotime($firstArray[$index]['startDate']) && strtotime($date['date']) < strtotime($firstArray[$index]['endDate']))
            return $date['date'];
    }
    return null;
}

foreach($firstArray as $key => $st_dates){
    $date = find_match($key);
    echo ($date != null) ? $date : "No match Found.";
    echo '<br/>';
}
```

**Result:**

```
07-05-2016
No match Found.
No match Found.
```

Comment: I tried like this already records duplicating. if record match that record has to go to the another array . if doesnt match it has to go to another array.
Please understand that both have multiple records..

Comment: want him to program the whole thing?

Comment: I didnt undestand . even a single tip can will help.. There is no way to use inArray.. I find it difficult.

Comment: As per your requirement, I update my answer, take a look.

Answer (score 1):

few things fixed as I debugged my code from above function. function has to be like that

```
function find_match($index){
$data=null;
global $firstArray, $secondArray;
foreach($secondArray as $date){
    if(strtotime($date['date']) > strtotime($firstArray[$index]['startDate']) && strtotime($date['date']) < strtotime($firstArray[$index]  ['endDate']))
        $data=$date['date'];
}
if($data !=null){
  return $data;
}else{
  return null
}
}
```